# Can't put background in HTML/CSS template for my work

Tags: php, html, css

I downloaded a free css/html template for a work, but I have a massive problem... I tried to change the background, but even if I saved and I deleted (yes, I did erase the previous image from my PC!) it still didn't change.. I tried to define the background directly in the html, but then it hasn't shown any photo as a background. What is the problem?

I searched for methods, but none of them worked.. I tried to analyze with the Inspect function on the page, after it had loaded, and if I changed the code in the console, the background changed. Even though, if I replaced the css file with the one I made in the browser, the first image came back, I think I can't get rid of it ever...

What I want:

```css
.main-home {
  background: url('../images/background.jpg') no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section id="home" class="main-home parallax-section">
   <div class="overlay"></div>
   <div id="particles-js"></div>
</section>
```

And the code my browser shows:

```
   .main-home {
      background: url('../images/home-bg.jpg') no-repeat;
      height: 100vh;

}
```

I expect to see the background.jpg as the actual background of the site, not this... And yes, I saved the css, I refreshed, tried other browsers, other stylings etc

Comment: what happens if you use your css code in a style in the same page?

Comment: try clearing the cache of your browser. or press CTRL+F5.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the cache? Try with `CTRL+F5`

Comment: inspect the image with your browser, right click the element and select "open in a new tab": what is the exact URL of the image?

Comment: Or try opening the page using incognito mode?

Comment: You also might have a PHP code cache module active

Comment: Or try to change the name of the CSS file and then link to the new file

Comment: is your background path good?

Comment: I tried to clean the cache, to change the css file's name, to open in incognito mode, but none of this methods worked...

Comment: @Lucian-DanielJimon did you include the right css? the images are different...

Comment: @xmastertje yes, I checked like a 100 times, but there is something else which is causing the problem, I can't possibly think what is it..

Comment: @Lucian-DanielJimon so if you would say `background-color: blue;` won't work either?

Comment: @xmastertje it won't work either..

Comment: @Lucian-DanielJimon I guess you don't include your css good....

Comment: @xmastertje At the beginning of the index.php I included the css in the following way:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 
I think it is the right way to do it...

Comment: @Lucian-DanielJimon in the `<head>` right? and iis the name and folder good?

Answer (score 0):

maybe your section id which is #home have another CSS. or please try using !important. like as below

```
background: url('../images/home-bg.jpg') !important;
```

Comment: The #home does not have any css reffering to the background, and the only row which include a background definition is the one I copied...also the !important does not work, I tried it as well

Answer (score 0):

Use property `!important` it's allows you to increase the priority of style.

```
.main-home {
  background: url('../images/background.jpg') no-repeat !important;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try add `background-size` and `background-position`

```
.main-home {
  background-image: url('../images/background.jpg');
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: center;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Look every css rules in the css file containing the image path
   'images/background.jpg'(eg:).
   Sometimes the image may be called from different css rules, like from 
   media query part.
2. Open Chrome inspector Network tab and check the Initiator column
   against the 'images/background.jpg' image request. Hover on it and
   it will show the code that triggered the image request.
   Example, if the image was triggered from a JS file the particular line 
   that caused the action will be shown in the Initiator section.
3. Also just as like every time, Clear Cache.

Comment: 1. I searched for other css code which would contain something with the background or with the images, but there is nothing else.
2. As you mentioned, I inspected the code, and it shows me just the 'home-bg.jpg', which is the photo I deleted, the old background...the new one doesn't even comes up, even if in my css that is the file which is set as background...
I cleared the cache several times, no result

Comment: will you please comment all the <script> tags and check again if any change is there

Comment: The scripts used by the template:
'<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/particles.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.parallax.js"></script>
<script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
'